# VS code navigate search results using cursor or keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to navigate the new search results window in VSCode using the cursor keys or keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

`Search: Focus Next Search Result` <kbd>F4</kbd>

`Search: Focus Previous Search Result` <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

both when the search editor is the active editor

Comment: Very nice! This saved me lots of clicking.

Comment: been looking for this for years