# Go to first match of ctrl-shift-f search

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to jump to the first match of ctrl-shift-f search.

For example I search for "newtest", and the I see the first match.

[image: vscode-search-result]

The first match is the right one.

#### How to to jump there without using the mouse?

Up to now I failed to find a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: It looks like you want the command found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61515986/836330: `Search: Focus Next Search Result`.  It goes to the first one if you are starting from an input box.

Comment: @Mark thank you very much for this link. This solves my question. I vote for closing my question, since it is a duplicate. The `F4` key works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to jump there immediately. But you can definitely do it the normal way of using <kbd>Tab</kbd> navigation.

Just keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the search results listing view is focused, and then use the <kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys to navigate between entries of the search results.

If no entry of the search results has been selected yet, then pressing either <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> the first time will select the first entry of the results list when it has focus.